# rotating 3D shape when it's described by set of arrays and without use of quaternions

Tags: c++, rotation

I have implemented a class Rectangle3D where all 8 point coordinates are described in the set of arrays:

```
   Rectangle3D rect_a({1.0f, 5.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f},//x coord
                   {3.0f, 6.0f, 3.0f, 7.0f, 2.0f, 9.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f},// y coord
                   {2.0f, 4.0f, 6.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 5.0f}); // z coord
```

I am using a quaternion library which will allow me to rotate this rectangle around its axis. However, for the testing purposes I need to find another way to rotate it, let's say 45 degrees around its Z axis, and get the new coordinated of the rotated figure. It must be done exactly in such form , this is a strict requirement. Unfortunately no option I tried gave me good results. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Addition: somehow I believe this formula should be used. The problem that math of this type is new for me too, where complex numbers are involved. The quaternion in terms of axis-angle is:

q = cos(a/2) + i ( x * sin(a/2)) + j (y * sin(a/2)) + k ( z * sin(a/2))

where:

a=angle of rotation.
x,y,z = vector representing axis of rotation.

Comment: The code goes for parallel computing therefore has certain restrictions. Only specific quaternion library developed for this purpose is used. However, I learned that this information should be useful. The biggest problem that this type of math is new for me too: The quaternion in terms of axis-angle is:

q = cos(a/2) + i ( x * sin(a/2)) + j (y * sin(a/2)) + k ( z * sin(a/2))

where:

a=angle of rotation.
x,y,z = vector representing axis of rotation.

Comment: It seems that I got answer I wanna share here: Because the axis of rotation is the z axis, the z coordinate remains unchanged. The transformed (new) coordinates of a corner (x,y,z) for anti-clockwise rotation angle 'a' are:

x' = xCos(a) - ySin(a)
y' = xSin(a) + yCos(a)
z' = z

Remember if you use the <cmath> trig functions, angles are measured in radians where 360 degrees = 2.PI radians.

So for a point (7,8,9) and rotation 50 degrees ( a = 50/360 * (2*PI) )

x' = 7Cos(a) - 8Sin(a)
y' = 7Sin(a) + 8Cos(a)
z' = 9

Comment: This worked, x' = xCos(a) - ySin(a) y' = xSin(a) + yCos(a) z' = z, question can be marked as solved